# passs text as key value pair along with the input data in chart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to input the key-value pair( company name and the value) as input data. I am a beginner to this library and just really dont know how to pass it I've read some docs but still couldn't figure it out. I want my chart to be like this.[image: desired chart]

and my chart look like this.[image: mychart]
I understand that I should input text from dataset but really dont know how to show it on the top and bottom of the chart. I am attaching my jusfiddle link in commment.

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>Sarmaaya Charts</title>

</head>
<style>
    * {
        color: rgb(66, 65, 65);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container m-5  ">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 m-1 bg-white">
                <h6 class=" ">Top Points Contributor </h6>
                <canvas id="bookValueVsPriceBookRatio"></canvas>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-R/QOHLpV1Ggq22vfDAWYOaMd5RopHrJNMxi8/lJu8Oihwi4Ho4BRFeiMiCefn9rasajKjnx9/fTQ/xkWnkDACg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

    <script>
        Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
        //global variables



        chartLabels = ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019, 2020', 'TTM']
        company = [4.32, 8.37, 6.37, 11.37, 7.37, 8.37, 6.37, 9.73, 4.89, 3.6,]
        sector = [-11.32, -10.37, -12.37, -10.37, -8.37, -4.37, -11.37, -4.73, -4.89]

        var bookValueVsPriceBookDatasets = {
            labels: chartLabels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: company,
                    backgroundColor: '#2FC798',
                    borderColor: '#2FC798',
                    borderWidth: 2.2,
                    lineTension: 0.4,
                    pointStyle: 'rectRot',
                    datalabels: {
                        align: 'start',
                        anchor: 'end',
                        align: 'end',
                        offset: 4,
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: sector,
                    backgroundColor: '#C72151',
                    borderColor: '#C72151',
                    borderWidth: 2.2,
                    lineTension: 0.4,
                    pointStyle: 'rectRot',
                    datalabels: {
                        align: 'start',
                        anchor: 'start',
                        align: 'start',
                        offset: 2,
                    }

                },

            ],

        }
        var chartStyling = {
            responsive: true,

            interaction: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false
            },
            layout: {
                padding: 1
            },
            elements: {
                point: {
                    hoverRadius: 6
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'grey',
                    borderWidth: 20,
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function (context) {
                            var label = context.dataset.label || '';
                            if (label) {
                                label += ': ';
                            }
                            if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                                label += context.parsed.y + '%';
                            }
                            return label;
                        }
                    }

                },
                elements: {
                    point: {
                        pointStyle: 'rect'
                    }

                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'top',
                    align: 'end',
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 5,
                        usePointStyle: true,
                    }

                },
                datalabels: {
                    display: true,
                    borderWidth: 0.5,
                    color: 'black',

                    formatter: function (value, context) {
                        return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
                    },
                    font: {
                        size: 11,
                        weight: 'bold',

                    }

                }
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    display: false,
                    grid: {
                        display: false,
                        lineWidth: 3
                    },
                    stacked: true,



                },
                x: {
                    display: false,
                    grid: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    stacked: true
                }
            }
        }

        var ctx5 = document.getElementById('bookValueVsPriceBookRatio').getContext('2d');

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx5, {
            data: bookValueVsPriceBookDatasets,
            options: chartStyling
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle link    https://jsfiddle.net/31vLm0op/ js

Comment: Please provide your code in your question with a live example, that makes it a lot easier and also got told to you by so when you tried to only post your fiddle link. Reason for this is that fiddle links can dissapear or be altered and thus make it so that others can't use this question if they have the same problem

Comment: The code is very long when i post it says you have very less text in question.

Comment: done. and thanks for telling me about the jsfiddle link

Comment: I am very close now I have passed all the text too. but now my chart stopped stacking. https://jsfiddle.net/gn6a4jzr/1/